# cbind doesn't attribute the name of the column

Tags: r, statistics, data, programming

I'm trying to create a new data frame that contains the row names and the first column of an existing data :
i tried this

```
#To take the rownames of my old data
New_data <- as.data.frame(row.names(old_data))
#To add the first column of my old data to a new data
New_data <- cbind(old_data[,1])
```

When i visualize my new data using View(New_Data) i don't see the name of my the first column just
V1

example

```
> old_data
   NAME  AGE  SEXE  
A   AQ   22    M
B   RT   14    M
C   DS   26    F
D   YY   19    M
E   IO   32    F
F   PP   20    F

New_data <- as.data.frame(row.names(old_data))
```

> 

```
New_data 
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

#add the first column of my old data to a new data

```
New_data <- cbind(old_data[,1])
>New_data
       V1
A      22
B      14
C      26
D      19
E      32
F      20
```

As you can see the name of the column in my new data is V1 , i want to bind the first column of my old data with the name of this column like this

```
>New_data
           Name
    A      22
    B      14
    C      26
    D      19
    E      32
    F      20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with cbind but rather with old_data[,1]. Since you are selecting only 1 column R will convert it into a vector, and a vector has no column name. Try `cbind(old_data[,1,drop=F])`.

Comment: It works, thank you very much